# R shiny fileInput large files

Tags: r, file-io, shiny

i have some problem with `fileInput` for R Shiny. Size limit is set to 5MB per default. 
Since the files i have to work with are very large (>50GB), I only need the datapath and or name of the file. Unfortunatly `fileInput` wants to upload the complete file or at least it is loading the file somehow and tells me that the file is too big after i have reached the 5MB limit.

How can I only hand over the path to my app without uploading the file?

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI ----
shinyUI(fluidPage(
h1("SAS Toolbox"),

tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("SASFat",
     sidebarPanel(h2("Input:"),
        actionButton("runSASFat","Run Job",width="100%",icon("paper-plane"), 
        style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),       

        wellPanel(
           #tags$style(".shiny-file-input-progress {display: none}"),
           fileInput("FEInp","Pfad FE input Deck:"), 
           fileInput("FERes","Pfad FE Results:") 
        ),
        wellPanel(
           checkboxGroupInput("options1","Auswertung:",c("Grundmaterial","Schweissnähte")),
           conditionalPanel(condition="$.inArray('Schweissnähte',input.options1) > -1", 
           sliderInput("filter", "Filter:", 0.75, min = 0, max = 1))
        ),
        wellPanel(
           radioButtons("solver", "Solver:", c("Ansys","Abaqus", "Optistruct")),
           conditionalPanel(condition="input.solver == 'Ansys'",selectInput("lic", "Lizenz",c("preppost","stba","meba"))) 
        ),
        wellPanel(
           checkboxGroupInput("options2","Optionen:",c("Schreibe LCFiles"))
        )
     ),
     mainPanel(br(),h2("Output:"),width="30%")
  ), 
  tabPanel("Nietauswertung"),
  tabPanel("Spannungskonzept EN12663")
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
# Define server logic ----
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$runSASFat, {
    FEInp <- input$FEInp
    FERes <- input$FERes
    opt1 <- input$options1 
    opt2 <- input$options2
    filter <- input$filter
    solver <- input$solver
    lic <- input$lic

    write(c(FEInp$datapath,FERes$datapath,opt1,opt2,filter,solver,lic),"ghhh.inp")
    })
})
```

Thanks in advance

Michael

Comment: I have not tested this with shiny but maybe `file.choose()` will be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of using `file.choose()` in a shiny app to obtain the local path of the file (and hence the file name):

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Choosing a file example"),


   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("filechoose",label = "Pick a file")
      ),

      mainPanel(
         textOutput("filechosen")
      )
   )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  path <- reactiveValues(
    pth=NULL
  )


  observeEvent(input$filechoose,{
    path$pth <- file.choose()
  })

   output$filechosen <- renderText({

      if(is.null(path$pth)){
        "Nothing selected"
      }else{
        path$pth
      }
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is this what you're after?

Comment: Yes thats it, thank you for your quick answer. I personally prefere the design of `fileInput`, but this is ok for me as well. I am just wondering why `fileInput` is uploading any files at all if the only values beeing extracted are "name", "size", "type" and "datapath". Makes no sense for me...

Comment: You can access the file content after uploading with `fileInput`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56223394/is-it-possible-to-use-the-unique-values-of-a-dataframe-column-that-is-yet-to-upl/56224251#56224251) for an example.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the example @MichaelBird. I adapted your code to let users cancel the request without choosing a file (your app crashed after canceling):

This by the way only works on the PC hosting the shiny app.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Choosing a file example"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("filechoose",label = "Pick a file")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("filechosen")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  path <- reactiveVal(value = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$filechoose, {

    tryPath <- tryCatch(
      file.choose()
      , error = function(e){e}
    )

  if(inherits(tryPath, "error")){
    path(NULL)
  } else {
    path(tryPath)
  }

  })

  output$filechosen <- renderText({
    if(is.null(path())){
      "Nothing selected"
    } else {
      path()
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

An alternative way would be to increase the maximum file size for uploads:

> By default, Shiny limits file uploads to 5MB per file. You can modify
>   this limit by using the shiny.maxRequestSize option. For example,
>   adding options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 30*1024^2) to the top of app.R
>   would increase the limit to 30MB.

See this RStudio [article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/upload.html).

Comment: Thanks for the improvements and also the note that this will only work on a local machine.