# Is it possible to use the unique values of a dataframe column that is yet to upload as 'choices' in the function pickerInput of shinyWidgets?

Tags: r, user-interface, datatable, shiny

I am building an interactive app with shiny. I am using the function pickerinput to select some filtering to apply to a dataframe that has to be uploaded by the user. Is there anyway to pass the unique values of a column of the dataframe to the argument 'choices' of this function?

Data frame to upload:

### X   | Y     | Z

### SNP | 1 | A

### del | 6 | T

### SNP | 5 | G

### del | 3 | G

### ins | 5 | A

### del | 8 | T

SNP | 3 | G

This is the code I have written:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)    #  for data tables
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarPanel(

        pickerInput("X", "X",
                    choices = unique(df$X) ),

    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("contents")
    )
))

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$contents <- renderDT({
    req(input$file1)
    df <- read.delim(input$file1$datapath,
                     header = TRUE,
                     sep = '\t')

    df <- df %>%  
      filter( X == input$X)
    return(df)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So that, after uploading the table, the user would have a select box whose choices would be the names of the rows of the column "X", that is: SNP, del, ins.

I have run this code but writing the choices myself (choices = c('SNP', 'del', 'ins' )), but I have no idea how to make the program to get the choices from an uploaded table.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to make the df object available to the ui environment (e.g. move the df outside of the server and not inside of the server or ui)

Answer (score 1):

`updatePickerInput` provides a way to realize this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)

fileData <-
  c(
    "X\tY\tZ",
    "SNP\t1\tA",
    "del\t6\tT",
    "SNP\t5\tG",
    "del\t3\tG",
    "ins\t5\tA",
    "del\t8\tT",
    "SNP\t3\tG"
  )


if(!file.exists("test_file.tsv")){
  writeLines(fileData, "test_file.tsv")
}

ui <-
  fluidPage(sidebarPanel(
    fileInput(
      "file1",
      "Choose TSV File",
      accept = c("text/tab-separated-values,text/plain", ".tsv")
    ),
    pickerInput("X", "X", choices = NULL)
  ),
  mainPanel(dataTableOutput("contents")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  DF <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)

    DF <- read.delim(input$file1$datapath,
                     header = TRUE,
                     sep = '\t')

  })

  observeEvent(DF(), {
    req(DF())
    updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "X", choices = unique(DF()$X))
  })

  filtered_DF <- reactive({
    req(input$X)
    DF() %>% filter(X == input$X)
  })

  output$contents <- renderDT({
    filtered_DF()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really useful